# Extract Column Names based on Key Words Pandas DF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame `df` like this, I would like to extract column names from data frame. Here is my `df`.

```
index my_numbers  nums
0     648702831   9
1      26533315   8
2           366   3
3     354701058   9
4      25708239   8
5         70554   5
6       1574512   7
7          3975   4
```

I need to check if `numbers` or `num` present, then I want to extract all those columns.

I did the following,

```
needed_cols = []
for i in df.columns:
    if 'numbers' or 'num' in i:
        needed_cols.append(i)
```

I get the following result,

```
['index', 'my_numbers', 'nums']
```

I need only these columns,

```
['my_numbers', 'nums']
```

How can I get them? Wondering why my code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `'num'` will always be in `'numbers'` can you check if a column contains `'num'`?

For example:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('num')]

Index(['my_numbers', 'nums'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thank you for answer. for my example it works. However, if I have columns, `city` or `cty` how can I do this? I am still having a little bit trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) your dataframe:

```
cols = df.filter(like='num').columns

print(cols)

Index(['my_numbers', 'nums'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's better than mine

Comment: How is it better?

Comment: I suppose I was thinking fewer operations = better performance, though truth be told, I didn't do any timings so it may very well be that it is not in fact a better answer. I still like the conciseness though